# Wait for a keypress in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-html

I'd like to pause execution of my Dart script (in a webpage) until the user hits a key.  The following code works, but I'm wondering if there's any better way of doing it:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

StreamSubscription sub;

Future main() async {
  KeyboardEvent k = await getkey();
  print(k.keyCode.toString());
}

Future<KeyboardEvent> getkey() async {
  Completer<KeyboardEvent> c = new Completer<KeyboardEvent>();
  sub = document.onKeyDown.listen((KeyboardEvent e){
    sub.cancel();
    c.complete(e);
  });
  return c.future;
}
```

**Update:** Gunter's solution below is ideal.  The code above shortens to:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

StreamSubscription sub;

Future main() async {
  KeyboardEvent k = await getkey();
  print(k.keyCode.toString());
}

Future<KeyboardEvent> getkey() async {
  return document.onKeyDown.first;
}
```

However, if I want to filter the keypresses I think I'm back to the former style:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

StreamSubscription sub;

Future main() async {
  KeyboardEvent k = await getkey([KeyCode.A,KeyCode.B,KeyCode.C,KeyCode.D]);
  print(k.keyCode.toString());
}

Future<KeyboardEvent> getkey([List<int> lst]) async {
  Completer<KeyboardEvent> c = new Completer<KeyboardEvent>();
  sub = document.onKeyDown.listen((KeyboardEvent e){
    if ((lst==null)||(lst.contains(e.keyCode))){
      sub.cancel();
      c.complete(e);
    }
  });
  return c.future;
}
```

Is that right?

**Update** Thanks again to Gunter!  Result is:

```dart
Future<KeyboardEvent> getkey([List<int> lst]) async {
  return document.onKeyDown.firstWhere((KeyboardEvent e)=>((lst==null)||(lst.contains(e.keyCode))));
}
```

Used as follows:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

Future main() async {
  KeyboardEvent k = await getkey();
  print(k.keyCode.toString());
  KeyboardEvent k = await getkey([KeyCode.A,KeyCode.B,KeyCode.C,KeyCode.D]);
  print(k.keyCode.toString());
}
```

Comment: sorry for offtopic, but what is mean keyword `async` after function name?

Comment: A function that contains an `await` function call must be marked as an `async` function.  See: https://www.dartlang.org/articles/await-async/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but as far as I remember changing

```dart
  Completer<KeyboardEvent> c = new Completer<KeyboardEvent>();
  sub = document.onKeyDown.listen((KeyboardEvent e){
    sub.cancel();
    c.complete(e);
  });
  return c.future;
```

to

```dart
  return document.onKeyDown.first;
```

should do the same.

#### Update

```dart
  return document.onKeyDown.firstWhere((KeyboardEvent e) => 1st.contains(e.keyCode));
```

(again not tested)

Comment: Thanks - that's much better!  I'll update my question to refer to your solution.